# Input resistance of ideal op. amp

Tags: feedback

Why is the input resistance of this ideal op. amp. equal to 10K? I know for a fact that that's the answer, I simply am not sure why. Since the 10k closer to the op. amp. is short circuited, why wouldn't the input resistance simply be infinity?

[image]

Comment: The input resistance of the op-amp is still "very high" or "approximately infinite". The input resistance of the inverting amplifier circuit shown is 10 kOhms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the op-amp is operating within regulation, the negative input terminal becomes a virtual ground. The amplifier will do what ever is need to maintain the negative terminal being equal to the positive terminal. Hence the negative terminal always looks like as if it were ground.

So all you see from the input is a 10k resistor to ground.

Comment: In this configuration.....

Comment: @sstobbe so is it 10k because of the left 10k or the right 10k? If it's due to the left, connected in series to vi, then that's still odd as normally in such configurations wouldn't Rin be inifinite?

Comment: @peripatein the left 10k, the negative terminal will always be equal to the positive terminal (ground) for an ideal negative feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Here the opamp is used in a circuit where it will try (and succeed since it is a proper circuit) to keep the voltage between the + and - inputs zero Volts.

The + input is grounded.

The opamp's output can only influence the - input via the 100 kohm feedback resistor.
The opamp will do "whatever is needed" to keep the - input at 0 V

So whatever you do at vi, the other side of that 10 kohm resistor will be at zero volt. This is called "virtual ground" because it is not connected to ground but behaves like it is.

So at vi you see a resistor of 10 kohm to ground. This means the input impedance **of this circuit** is 10 kohm.

Note how that 10 kohm resistor to ground does actually nothing. You could remove it and nothing changes. Why ? Because there is zero volt across it. Meaning no current flows meaning it is "not there". Note that this is only true when the opamp is ideal, in a practical circuit the 10 kohm to ground does influence the circuit's behavior.

Comment: +1 However, I would not quite say the pull-down does nothing. It does nothing when a signal is attached, but if the input is unplugged it stops the thing from picking up any stray noise in the vicinity. Well almost, definitely much better than the alternative.

Comment: @Trevor I agree with your comment. But I did not want to complicate things and considered the opamp to be ideal and then the 10 k ohm to ground does nothing. In the real world with non-ideal opamps indeed it does influence the behavior of the circuit (noise, large signal behavior etc).